# Probability of a particular triangular area inside a sphere?

Tags: probability, geometry

Let's say I have a sphere. All points are equally probable inside the sphere. Three points are randomly chosen. What is probability distribution of the areas of the triangle? Is this solvable?

Comment: Idea: embed each such triangle within an inner sphere of equal or smaller volume and a diameter equal to the triangle's longest side. Then maybe the probability should be proportional to $1-\frac{v_{s}}{V_s}$ where $V_s$ is the volume of the larger sphere, $v_s$ is the volume of the smaller one. This is purely from intuition but the idea is, the larger the volume of the inner sphere, the less we are free to move it around within the larger sphere. Bottom line: maybe you can first solve the same problem for the probability of an embedded sphere's volume, then try and transfer it to areas...